# Sales Tax & Bill (part 2) (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was able to make the "salestax" and the "total" have two decimal places but I cannot seem to make the price print with two decimal places because I keep running into errors trying to format it correctly.

```
price = float(input("Price: $ "))
tax = .05
salestax = (price*tax)
total = ((price*tax)+ price)
print("Sales Tax: $", format(salestax,'.2f'))
print("Total: $", format(total,'.2f'))
```

Any suggestions?

```
Price: $99.00
Sales Tax: $4.95
Total: $103.95
```

Comment: the `.2f` seems working for me

Comment: i don't see a problem with the code

Comment: Your output shows two decimal places and no errors. Makes it hard to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3.6+, I think it's a *lot* cooler to implement this with f-strings:

```py
import os
from getpass import getpass


print('Price: $ ', end='', flush=True)
price = float(getpass(''))

# Clears the line with prompt and input
clear = 'cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'
os.system(clear)

tax = .05
salestax = price * tax  # remove redudant parentheses here
total = price * tax + price  # remove again, redundant paranthesis (mult before add)

print(f'Price: $ {price:.2f}')
print(f'Sales Tax: $ {salestax:.2f}')
print(f'Total: $ {total:.2f}')
```

Note: be careful about the `getpass` usage. It doesn't work with interactive terminals as you'd expect. You'd need a regular terminal like a windows prompt to see the expected output.

Test above using input:

```
$ Price: $ 123.456789

Price: $ 123.46
Sales Tax: $ 6.17
Total: $ 129.63
```

Comment: how would i do that for the price, being that its an input...

Comment: oh, i didn't read your question carefully

Comment: I see what you were asking now

Comment: seems to be same as the other two variables.. unless I'm missing something? I updated my answer for clarification

Comment: is there a way to make it so that the input doesn't print and it simply reads the price, sales tax, and total?

Comment: ah, you're probably looking for `getpass`

Comment: updated my answer above -I guess that *mostly* does what you were looking for.

Comment: I want to make it so that, when I input 99, all it reads is

Price: (next line)
Sales Tax: (next line)
Total: (next line).... and it doesnt include the input itself. Like i want to ask the user the price, have them input it, then only have those three things print, not the actual question and input

Comment: would you be able to update the question with an example of the desired output? kind of hard to understand what you mean. also you might want to use a different terminology if possible (I was confused when you said **reads** as I interpreted it as reading user input)

Comment: sure I will now

Comment: sorry, I still didn't follow that. please update your question to format it as I've done in the 2nd part of my answer above (you can use code fences and wrap multiple lines with ``` to format them as I have)

Comment: I updated the originally question (the bottom)

Comment: Is the `Price: $` prompt different from what you want to show as the output for the Price?

Comment: For clearing the line with the prompt and input, you might try `os.system('cls')` - it only kinda works for me on windows, but that should kinda do what you want